# Can Haxe take screenshot of entire desktop screen?

Tags: screen, haxe

can Haxe access screen pixels? I wanted to count average brightness and hue of some areas on the screen but I can't find anything of such in documentation.

Ultimately I wanted to see if it's possible to create ambilight using Haxe, but that is not part of the question for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Optimistically**, this would be depending on your target (C++, Flash, JS etc). Forget about all web languages here (JS, Flash would never be granted that kind of permission for obvious security reasons).

**Pessimistically**, it would require the underlaying libraries you have access to to be granted access to the screen by the OS. Maybe possible in languages like C++ *if* you run the program with admin rights. Note that modern windowed systems would have a lot of reasons to not provide access to the screen, or through special authorizations granted via the admin panels of your OS (thinking about 3rd party remote administrative tools here, where admins can take control of a remote computer and seeing its screen).

So if you don't want to lose time, follow this procedure:

1. Check the APIs for your targeted OS, to see if it's really possible and under which conditions.
2. If 1. i possible, find a proper target for Haxe (probably C++),
3. Declare some externs for the library you're going to use and do the coding.

This is *a lot* of work obviously, as even if you do that you will then have to write the analyzing code and its response, and for an undetermined result as you'll probably spend a lot of time in step 1. Even if you achieve that, you'll probably be the only person using your program, as the process to install it will be very complicated (unless you spend 2 more  weeks writing a complex installer...).

Turns out the question belongs more to your specific OS than to the Haxe realm.

(You'd be better off forgetting about that IMHO ;)